# Resposta errada e não sei o porquê em Python

Tags: python

To com uma duvida na seguinte questão:

> Foram anotadas as idades e alturas de K alunos. Faça um Programa que
>   determine quantos alunos com mais de 13 anos possuem altura inferior à
>   média de altura de todos os alunos. A entrada deve conter um numero N
>   na primeira linha que indica o número de alunos no caso de teste. Em
>   seguida, cada linha contém idade e altura.

O meu código ta assim

```
idade = []
altura = []
somaAltura = []
cont = 0

qntAlunos = int(raw_input('Informe a quantidade de alunos: '))

for i in range(qntAlunos):
    print 'Informe a idade:'
    idade.append(int(raw_input()))
    print 'Informe a altura:'
    altura.append(float(raw_input()))
    somaAltura = sum(altura)
    media = somaAltura / qntAlunos

for j in range(qntAlunos):
    if altura[j] < media and idade[j] > 13:
        cont += 1


print cont
```

Mas pq quando eu rodo o programa, o contador nunca da a resposta correta?

Comment: "*Em seguida, cada linha contém idade e altura*", você está lendo idade e altura em linhas distintas.

Comment: Você está calculando a soma de alturas e a média e a ada volta do primeiro for. Não afeta o resultado, mas seria mais eficiente fazer esse cálculo fora do laço. E, como o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse, tem um problema na leitura. `idade, altura = raw_input().split()` é mais ou menos o que vai precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique seu contador. Você define ele como "cont1 = 0" mas utiliza "cont += 1". Defina ele como cont = 0, mantendo mesma nomenclatura da variável que dará certo. Abraço e bons estudos.

Comment: Desculpa, eu esqueci de mudar isso, pois estava fazendo testes para tentar achar o erro. Na verdade, a variável está igual a quando eu declaro e o erro persiste.